# Assembly: How to store string inside .asciiz?

Tags: assembly, mips

In assembly, is there a way to store an input from the user as string into a .asciiz instead of .word?

I know sw and lw but how to do it with .asciiz?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I had to remove my code snippet, because it's a full program for an Assignment.

As you see, this is the application I'm trying to make, when the program read the filename from the user which is stored in `userInput` I cannot execute option `processImage`, but I use `myInput2` which already has the name of my image file I want to read, `processImage` will work just fine.

Comment: Please post a solution that you've already tried out.

Comment: Can you kindly check again, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You need to allocate some space for the input. See the example in my answer.

Comment: I think I found the problem, when I'm letting the user specify the image name my code does not work, but If I already defined the image name inside an asciiz it will work. Can you think of any issue which causes this?  Yes I have read your updated answer, I have allocated a length 20 for the input name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sw` and `lw` are runtime instructions while `.asciiz` is a compile time assembler directive.
You can use `.asciiz` to allocate space for the user input if you want, but you still need to fill it at runtime, for example by reading characters in a loop and storing them using `sb` or using `read string` or similar system call if you have one.

The `.asciiz` is just syntactical sugar to make it easier to store strings, it's equivalent to specifying a bunch of bytes, just that you don't have to manually figure out the values.
`.asciiz "a"` is the same as `.byte 97, 0`.

**Update**

```
    li $a1, 6     # length
    la $a0, str1  # buffer
    li $v0, 8     # read string call number
    syscall 

.data
str1: .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
str2: .word 0, 0, 0
str3: .space 6
.comm str4, 6
str5: .asciiz "12345"
```

The above `str1` through `str5` are all equivalent except that `str5` isn't initialized to all zeroes. You can use any of those on the `la $a0` line.

Comment: I'll try this when I get back home, so what you're saying is I can't put the string I received from the user to a .asciiz? Instead I have to put it in .Byte ? My problem here is that I want to load the filename later. And the only way I know to use is by la $a0, filename. But this doesn't work with .word

Comment: You can put it in `.asciiz` too, and `la` works with labels, it doesn't care about the directive used to specify data (if any).

Comment: Can you kindly check my question again, I have updated it. It has the program code I'm trying to do, read the lines below and you will understand my problem.